# Cannot see the Glassfish adapter after installing plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, glassfish-3

I've installed Glassfish 3.1.1 and Eclipse Indigo onto a Win 7 machine but cannot add the Glassfish server via Eclipse's Servers view.
Oracle Glassfish Server Tools 1.8 is also installed but despite this there is no Glassifish entry in the list of avilable server adaptors.
I will continue to scour the web for a way around this but if anyone can advise I'd be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the JavaEE development edition of Eclipse, and in that go to the Eclipse Marketplace where you can find and install the Glassfish adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart eclipse two times before it appeared. This seems like a bug to me but I'm new in the Eclipse world